# Overflow one child to fixed height parent

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to set `p` overflow inside the rest of section (not consider h4):

```css
section {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

p {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: do you mean, the grey background to take over the entire <p> as well?

Comment: Yes, but all inside 150px height.

Comment: Give the `<p>` a grey background ?

Answer (score 1):

Hans, I did it inside 150px height. Hope it works for you.

```css
section {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: I want to overflow just `p` element. do you know any way?

Comment: sorry, it's confusing to me). Please share any screenshot for the output you are looking for if you have.

Comment: if you want to overflow only `<p>` element then do not apply `overflow:auto` to `<section>` element.